# Inconsistent time format on front pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, timestamps, homepage

Normally, the time on the front pages is displayed in "secs", "mins" and "hours". However, if there's activity on a question, and you click the little bar at the top to refresh the list (without reloading), they're suddenly reduced to "s", "m" and "h":

[image]
[image]

The state on the left is restored once you reload the page. The above screenshots are from a beta site (CodeGolf.SE), but I've confirmed that the same happens on SU and SF (so I'm pretty sure it's a network-wide thing).

I tried finding this bug on meta, but all I could find was the same behaviour on profile pages [which was fixed a couple of years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198744/201409).

(PS: I've noticed that there's some odd rearranging of content upon reloading an auto-refreshed site about two days ago and have since been trying to figure out what exactly moves on the page. :D)

**Edit:** There also seem to be a few other things which trigger the change from long to short format. I just had SU and SF open in tabs in the background, with the long format when I left them. When I revisited them after a few minutes, they had changed to the short format.

Comment: That's not AJAX, it's web sockets connection.

Comment: Hm...the scenario in your edit should be fixed, per [Why do the client and server sides of StackExchange use different abbreviations for time spans?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246092) I wonder if there was a regression.

Comment: @TimStone yeah, the fix you linked only fixed the server-side rendering, but left the relativetime updates using the short format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix is rolling out with next build (rev `2015.2.12.3070` on meta, `2015.2.12.2293` on sites).